# Autofill DatePicker input date python using selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I want to select today date from input type DatePicker:

[image: datapicker]

.css:

```
<div class="input-group">
<input class="form-control is-calendarsPicker ui-inputtext ui-corner-all ui-state-default ui-widget ui-state-filled" pinputtext="" readonly="" type="text" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" placeholder=" ">
<!----><a class="input-group-append ng-star-inserted" href="#/vaccine-registration/register-visitor"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar-alt"></i></span></a></div>
<div class="calendars-month-row"><div class="calendars-month">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="jd2459437.5 calendars-selected" title="اختر أربعاء, 8 11">11</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

I tried:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
if __name__ == "__main__":
   element = driver.find_element_by_name("birthdate")
   element.click()  # Focus input field
          
   element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("calendars-month-row")
   element.click()  # Focus input field
```

put the result is :

2021-08-18

Any kind of help please?

Answer (score 0):

to click on current select date of the date picker, you can use the below **css** :

```
a[class$='calendars-selected']
```

in code :

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a[class$='calendars-selected']").click()
```

Comment: No just open calendars and nothing happens.

Comment: Do you know how to check nodes in HTML DOM ?

Comment: This is xpath of date '18' 
//*[@id="index-page"]/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/a

Comment: yes from where you copied, paste this `a[class$='calendars-selected']` and see if we have 1/1 matching node